# Pass captures to lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

Would there be a way to reuse my lambda?

```
constexpr auto contains(const suit_t& suit) const noexcept -> const bool
{
    return std::find(cbegin(), cend(), [suit](card_t* card) constexpr { return card->suit == suit; }) != cend();
}

constexpr auto count(const suit_t& suit) const noexcept -> const long long
{
    return std::count_if(cbegin(), cend(), [suit](card_t* card) constexpr { return card->suit == suit; });
}
```

When I try to do the following the lambda doesn't know what `suit` is.

```
auto lambda = [suit](card_t* card) constexpr { return card->suit == suit; }

constexpr auto contains(const suit_t& suit) const noexcept -> const bool
{
    return std::find(cbegin(), cend(), lambda) != cend();
}

constexpr auto count(const suit_t& suit) const noexcept -> const long long
{
    return std::count_if(cbegin(), cend(), lambda);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make it a function?

Comment: Or use a a functor with a constructor.

Comment: You could also have a lambda returning a lambda like `[](suit_t& suit) {return [suit](card_t* card) { ... } }`, but that is probably the ugliest solution in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something along the lines of this:

```
class MyLambdaReplacement {
   const suit_t& _suit;
public:
   MyLambdaReplacement(const suit_t& s) : _suit{ s } {}
   constexpr bool operator()(card_t* card) {
      return card->suit == _suit;
   }
};

constexpr auto contains(const suit_t& suit) const noexcept -> const bool
{
    return std::find(cbegin(), cend(), MyLambdaReplacement{ suit }) != cend();
}
```